# Как записать график отношения одного к другому

Tags: php

Есть ли какая нибудь хитрая конструкция позволяющая без кучи If  записиать график отношения
одного к другому. 
Например 6-8 по графику равно 90-95

Comment: Чего-то непонятно. Причем тут график? Откуда 6-8 и 90-95? Это дискретная функция у вас?

Comment: прямая зависимость

Comment: про график не понял, но эта штука называется array

   array('6-8'=>'90-95','10-50'=>'60-90');

Comment: У нас новый штатный телепат :-)

Comment: Это пропорции, 7ой класс средней школы =)

Comment: да телепат классный) Я сильно извиняюсь не совсем корректно и полно описал задание.

есть число нужно искать по этому числу прямую зависимость
 соответственно если наше число 6 то это будет 90 если 8 то 95 
на бумажке это просто рисуется графиком на оси координат.

Comment: а если число 10 ? то 100 ? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D75%2Bx*2.5

Answer (score 1):

Если есть какая то математическая модель, то можно в цикле подставляя х в какую то функцию получить координаты y и работать с графиком.
Это конечно, если я правильно стелепатировал Ваш вопрос.